# If I store a static session token in JS for use with AJAX, will it be secure against CSRF?

Tags: javascript, ajax, security, csrf

I've been reading about CSRF and XSS vulnerabilities for a few days now, and trying to come up with a solution that's 1) easy to implement and use, 2) uses Javascript to do a lot of heavy lifting, and 3) makes it virtually impossible to perform a CSRF attack against.

I haven't seen a solution like the one I'm about to describe. I'm hoping this doesn't mean that it's leaky.

I've come up with the following solution, based on my knowledge of AJAX and JS. This code assumes the user has passed through a login screen, and a session variable has been set on the server **and** in a cookie, with the same values.

It's easier to paste the code in and document it, rather than explain what it's doing. This code would be run in the page the user sees immediately after logging in:

```
<script>
// this is the constructor:
function Controller(){

  //the following 2 variables are private, and inaccessible via JS calls

    var secretToken;  //this holds the session token, but cannot be read by the browser

    //returns the session token from the server
    var x = new ajaxObject('AJAX/retrieve_session_cookie.lasso'); 
    x.callback = function(responseText, responseStatus){
      secretToken = responseText;
    }

  //this is a private function, again inaccessible via JS calls

    function getCookie(){
      x.update();
    }

  //the following 2 functions are publicly accessible

    //just a test function to ensure that secretToken is invisible
    this.tell = function(){
      alert(secretToken);
    }

    //privileged function that calls a private function, to load the token into a private variable
    this.initialize = function(){
      getCookie();
    }
}

E = new Controller();
E.initialize();

</script>
```

The variable `secretToken` can't be read by the user, as it's a private member variable of the controller object.

In `retrieve_session_cookie.lasso`, I'm checking for a valid session, and matching the session variable with the browser's cookie. If both these conditions are met, the session variable is returned in plain text, where it's set as `secretToken` in the object `E`. By double-checking to see if the cookie matches the session token, I would hope that it would be impossible obtain the session token via CSRF, as it can't forge a cookie. Typing in 'AJAX/retrieve_session_cookie.lasso' would return nothing, unless it was typed in by the user while in a valid session, and from the user's computer only.

Also, now that my controller has local access to the session token, I could 'burn in' the session token with every AJAX request, so I don't even have to think about it passing a token anymore, each time an AJAX file is requested. All the AJAX objects and requests would be initialized as private members in the controller object's constructor, so nobody could access / modify the callback functions to disclose the session token.

Passing the session token with every AJAX call would protect every other AJAX file, as they would all perform the same check for the cookie matching the session token before returning any data. And, in my programming, there would be one less variable to worry about.

If I were to move ahead with a controller implemented this way, would there be ANY way for the token to be accessed / exploited, either by the user or a malicious coder via CSRF?

Comment: Are you using ASP.NET server side? Is the issue you're trying to solve the fact that the WebService you're calling isn't session enabled? If so, you could just decorate your web service method with [WebMethod(EnableSession = true)]. Then you have access to the logged in user session.

Comment: You just said a user with a valid session can go to `AJAX/retrieve_session_cookie.lasso` and view the token. Other than that, it seems rather sound, but I'm sure someone with a reason to break your security, could still manage...

Comment: @Berhard : I'm actually programming in Lasso (it's an obscure server-side language). It does support sessions, so I thought it would be a good idea to set a session variable for an AJAX token, that was identical to a token value in the cookie.

Comment: @Khez : A logged-in user certainly has the ability to view their own token. I don't quite know how to prevent this. Since it's a publicly-accessible script on the webserver that's referenced explicitly in JS, there's no way (that I know of) around it. However, since other approaches scatter the token throughout the DOM, how are they any more secure? The token's just a right-click / 'Inspect Element' away.

Comment: Why are you so afraid that a user can see his own token ? o.O

Comment: @Khez : I'm not really afraid of the user themselves being able to see their token. What I'm really concerned about is a potential XSS attack. If you bury the token somewhere in the DOM (say, as a hidden value with every form), then an XSS attack would be able to traverse the DOM and retrieve it. With a private variable in a controller object, this potential vulnerability is mitigated. Thoughts?

Comment: Well consider this then, following up on your code: new ajaxObject('AJAX/retrieve_session_cookie.lasso');x.callback=function(responseText, responseStatus){doSomethinvEvil(responseText);}. I can insert that block of code and I'd still be able to get your token :-?. You are never truly safe.

Comment: @Khez : Aha! Except that, there's no way to access the x variable from the outside, because it's a private variable inside the controller object. x, and its callback function, cannot be modified once E is instantiated - so, you wouldn't be able to retrieve the token this way.

Comment: True, but I can insert a script that just does that... right? :)

Comment: @Khez : Your script wouldn't be able to find the variable, or call a method on it, because it's invisible to the window context. Perhaps, if you were able to assign the scope of a function to the controller, this could be worked around - but I'm not sure.

Comment: You're saying I can't create inject this ?! <script>x=new ajaxObject('AJAX/retrieve_session_cookie.lasso');x.callback=function(responseTex­t, responseStatus){doSomethinvEvil(responseText);}</script>

Comment: Ah.. I see what you're saying. Sure, you could simply use the same class to instantiate a new variable in the window context, and assign your own callback. But, that assumes that XSS has successfully been injected. If I make sure that all the data that's input into the system is sanitized, is there any other way for this script to get injected?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all it is trivial for a **user** to obtain your token and for CSRF this doesn't matter at all.  Anything you transfer to the user can be intercepted,  anything being sent from javascript can be [tampered with](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/tamper-data/).  Cookies are always easy to replay (Who cares about forging them? Its just a random number.),  and this doesn't matter as long as you use HTTPS.  To be honest I don't think that this security system addresses CSRF at all,  in fact I'm not sure what you are trying to protect against.   It doesn't matter where your `.lasso`  files are or what they contain.

What matters is the GET and POST requests can be forged.  The whole point of having a CSRF token is that a 3rd party can't create an exact GET/POST request without knowing somthing about the site(and a simple token written as a hidden value works because of [Same-Origin Policy](http://code.google.com/p/browsersec/wiki/Part2)).  **Don't roll your own security system**,  pick a solution off of the [Cross-Site Request Forgery Cheat Sheet](http://www.owasp.org/index.php/Cross-Site_Request_Forgery_%28CSRF%29_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet).

Comment: I read through the Cheat Sheet you linked (familiar with OWASP - that's where I learned about these vulnerabilities before). I'm doing a lot of things that the cheat sheet already suggests: double submitting cookies, checking headers, using POST for all requests, etc. I just don't like the thought of the token being visible to the DOM, since XSS attacks could potentially retrieve it while the user's session is valid. This is both an XSS and CSRF issue, not just CSRF.

Comment: I'm a little unclear, also, as to what you mean when you mention HTTPS. Do your comments above depend on the use of HTTPS, or was that just a casual remark? I don't plan on using anything but HTTP (with, perhaps, an embedded HTTPS iframe for credit-card transactions).

Comment: @StickByAtlas XSS bypasses most CSRF protection systems, I am skeptical that this solution really solves this problem. The HTTPs comment isn't casual its an important part of the OWASP top 10.  HTTPS is all or nothing.  Either its trivial to hack accounts by sniffing the network (like open wifi) or its not.  Its pointless to transmit passwords over https and then transmit the real authentication token (a cookie or session id)  over http.

Comment: @StickByAtlas Also,  XSS is more harmful than CSRF.  If you have XSS you can just hijack that session by grabbing `document.cookie` or call any javascript functions available.  What happens when a user clicks "submit",  what if an xss payload calls `.submit()` on the form?  I think your going about this the wrong way.

Comment: @Rook : You raise a valid point about session hijacking, and that's something to consider in a separate question. Regarding your example XSS scenario - I'm attempting to build a JS controller that's impervious to manipulation. Any form submissions, or any interface elements that change the application state, would always check to ensure the process was initiated from the correct DOM event (e.g. `Event.findElement()` in Prototype.) The handlers would all be private functions that couldn't be access otherwise. No good?

Comment: @StickByAtlas My point is that how do you know that a user filled out a form and submitted it?  It could be something that was done with CSRF or XSS or [ClickJacking](http://blog.kotowicz.net/2011/03/exploiting-unexploitable-xss-with.html).  You can fill out forms and submit them with javascript alone.  Have you ever seen a CSRF Exploit? Here is [one I have written](http://www.exploit-db.com/exploits/7389/)